# Click on the element which is visible after mouse hovering

Tags: selenium, mouse

I have to click on a tile which is generated after mouse hovering. I wrote the code below but it is still not working.

```
WebElement FrontElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='sol-itm-bx relative front-app-nm']/span[text()='UI Auto Test12345']"));
WebElement BackElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='relative back-app-desc']/span[text()='UI Auto Test12345']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

builder.moveToElement(FrontElement);
builder.perform();
builder.clickAndHold(FrontElement);
BackElement.click();
```

Comment: Please tell us how it fails to do what you want? Do you get an error message? Is something you expect to happen, not happening? (Edit your question with this information.)

Comment: i did not got any error message in my code what happened when i hover the mouse on a element then its back part is display and i want to click on the backpart of it

Answer (score 2):

To use the `Actions()` class you need to chain the actions together. Separate commands won't work in the way you want.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='sol-itm-bx relative front-app-nm']/span[text()='UI Auto Test12345']")))
     .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='relative back-app-desc']/span[text()='UI Auto Test12345']")))
     .click().perform();
```

Note: I've separated the lines for ease of reading.
EDIT: 'build' to 'builder' NullPointerException